# load a website as a frame to my site (google analytics)

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, traffic

Let us say I load an external website to my current website using iframe.

Does this load appear on the other website as traffic using google analytics? Also, is my current site considered a referral to the other site?

In this way, I guess, I generate traffic to the other website without the visitor leaving my
website? Right?

Any comments are welcome!
Thanks, 
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
Yes.
Yes.

Unless the other site uses a framebuster.

Comment: Thank you Slaks! I appreciate your quick response!